# Shadow cubemapping?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, terminology

I am working on a game with C++ and OpenGL 3.2. I have successfully implemented directional shadow maps and now I'd like to upgrade them to shadow cube maps (for point lights). I've done some Googling and I can't seem to find much solid info on how to achieve this.

What is this technique called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Omnidirectional Shadow Mapping".
Google has lots of hints for that.

Comment: A good idea would be to highlight the most relevant links you find on Google.